# sending form data to one of two urls (servlets)

Tags: javascript, forms, servlets

i have a form with two text fieds and a normal submit button. when i click the submit button the form data should be sent to one of the two ("/missing" or "/fine") servlets on my localhost (Tomcat server). if the data in any text field is missing then the target servlet is "/missing" otherwise the target is "/fine".

```
<form name=f1 id=f1>
    <script>
        function check()
        {       
            if(tn.value.length==0 || ta.value.length==0)
              f1.submit('mylocaltomcathost/two/missing'); //?what is alternative to this?
            else
              f1.submit('mylocaltomcathost/two/fine'); //?what is alternative to this?          
        }
    </script>
    Enter name:<input name="txtName" type="text" id="tn"></input> <br>
    Enter Age:   <input name=txtAge type="text" id="ta"> </input> <br>
    <input type=button value="send..." onclick="check()">
</form>
```

i understand that submit() does not take any arguments, but an operation of that kind should take place. so **please let me know what should i use instead of f1.submit(...)**

When i use window.open('mylocaltomcathost/two/missing') it is working fine, but i need to submit data. As window.open() is opening the servlet, i make sure there is no problem with the servlet and connections.
Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: i replaced **http://localhost:4040** with **>mylocaltomcathost** as there was an error showing **"localhost not allowed in a link ..."** when i submitted this question

Answer (score 0):

You should substitute `form.action` to the corresponding one. i.e.

```
function check()
    {       
        if(tn.value.length==0 || ta.value.length==0) {
          f1.action="mylocaltomcathost/two/missing";
          f1.submit();
        } else {
          f1.action="mylocaltomcathost/two/fine";
          f1.submit(); //?what is alternative to this?          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the action on the form to the correct url

```
<form action="/" name=f1 id=f1>

f1.action = '/missing;
```

or 
    f1.action = '/fine';

then call

```
 f1.submit();
```